# Converting flow rate from normal/standard liters per minute to cubic meters per second

Tags: airflow, standards, unit

I'm really confused about these three units commonly used for measuring airflow:

- cubic meters per second (m<sup>3</sup>/s)
- normal liters per minute (NLPM)
- standard liters per minute (SLPM)

I would appreciate if you could help me know how to convert them to each other. For example, is

$$1 \, m^3/s = 1 \, NLPM * 60 / 1000 $$

correct?

Answer (score 2):

The conversions can be found at this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_litre_per_minute)

$$ 1 \frac{m^3}{s}  = 1000 [NLPM] \frac{T_{gas}}{293.15}\cdot\frac{14.696 [psi]}{P_{gas}} = 1000 [SLPM] \frac{T{gas}}{273.15}\cdot\frac{14.504 [psi]}{P_{gas} [psi]} $$

where:

- $T_{gas}$: is the temperature that the gas is flowing
- $P_{gas}$: is the pressure that the gas is flowing

Comment: yeah I saw that Wikipedia page and that's why I'm confused. It seem like that NLPM and SLPM are mass flow rates not volumetric flow rates. Is that correct?

Comment: In a way,  they are. Because indirectly when comparing NLPM and SLPM flow rates, you are comparing the mass that flows. The mass of the gas that flows cannot be directly measured, (while the volume can), so it can be used to estimate the mass rate.

Answer (score 2):

Different from technical mass units, a technical volume unit always depends on ambient conditions.

The difference between NLPM and SLPM is:

We put 1 liter of air at 0° C and sea level 1013.25 mBar in a cylinder. This is called “Normal Flow”. When the temperature is raised to 20°C, the molecules need more space. The piston will go up and the volume increases to 1.073 liters - exactly 7.3%. This is called “Standard Flow.”

However, there are different standards: In Europe, the “Standard” is defined at 20°C. In the United States, the Farenheit temperature scale is used so 70°F is standard, which is 21.1°C. NASA uses a 60°F standard and China uses 15°C.
The most important thing is to know which standard we are referencing.